# How to do AWS Step Function Retry Without an Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am trying to achieve a functionality where I want to retry a step multiple times based on the result of the previous invocation. i.e. if stepA returns true I can proceed, if false, do a retry for the same step. But AWS step function retries works only on Errors and that too not with runtime errors.

Is there a way I can achieve this retry in AWS Step function.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the [Choice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) State. Here's a simple example how this could look like:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Task",
  "States": {
    "Task": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME",
      "Next": "Retry?"
    },
    "Retry?": {
      "Type" : "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.retry",
          "BooleanEquals": true,
          "Next": "Task"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "EndState"
    },
    "EndState": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe in this case you need to define a parameter, call it "retried" with false initial value, upon the exception don't raise and error, in the first try set "rertied" to true and move the prev step, in the second try check the flag and if its true move to next step